# Jquery week hour schedule like torrent style

Tags: jquery-plugins

My manager ask me for develop a ui selectinh hour intervals in days of week.
He wants to select hours with snipping mouse.

he gave me torrent schedule as example.. and I search many on the net but most of them quite same and smiliar I need a find plugin that looks like torrent schedule and gives same functionality..

Its not ensure what he wants but I will have to use [this](http://robmonie.github.io/jquery-week-calendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html)(cause it looks fine and a little bit smiliar) if I dont find better.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a plugin that answers whats I ask for.. http://fullcalendar.io/ 
 its pretty awesome and well documented plugin.